# Watson Conversation_Nodes that has no response

Tags: json, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

So I wrote this JSON code just like the following

```
{
  "context": {
    "action": {
      "dates": "$dates",
      "command": [
        "check-dates"
      ]
    },
    "output": {
      "text": {
        "values": [
          "$dates, Do you want to pick this as a designated date?"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "output": {}
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't count as a response as I've expected and I tried to erase that last "output" thing but it just pops out whenever I click the node again for some reasons. Any suggestion is more than a welcome :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON have some incorrect syntax. You have not closed all JSON values in the context

For have some answer:

```
{
  "context": {
    "action": {
      "dates": "$dates",
      "command": [
        "check-dates"
      ]
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Your answer here."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want one response for the user, give the [] empty like:

```
{
  "context": {
    "action": {
      "dates": "$dates",
      "command": [
        "check-dates"
      ]
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        ""
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend, for you make sure if your Syntax from your JSON is correct [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the link! Apparently, there's some problem with Watson Conversation JSON editor

Comment: I don't know why but, it just self-corrects itself by putting those last output thing but as I copied the values again, it worked fine.

Comment: {
  "context": {
    "action": {
      "dates": "$dates",
      "command": [
        "check-dates"
      ]
    },
    "output": {
      "text": {
        "values": [
          "$dates, your date?"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "$dates, your date?"
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: This is because your JSON are correctly now and sometimes IBM correct for you, or show the error with your json. I test your json within your question and have one incorrect syntax.